# APi Refresh token error

Tags: php, curl, onedrive

I don't understand... We have no problem for refresh token with this code with OneDrive classical account:

```
Curl url: https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf
Curl post: 1
Curl postfields: client_id, refresh_token, grant_type, redirect_uri, client_secret
```

But with OneDrive Enterprise account, it doesn't work. We have this error:

```
*object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(13) "invalid_grant"
  ["error_description"]=>
  string(87) "The provided value for the input parameter 'refresh_token' or 'assertion' is not valid."
}*
```

Is the call different with One Drive Enterprise?

Comment: I think, that your parameter `grant_type` set scopes, which you haven't access in the classic version.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, question is:

What's the call to use for a refresh token with a OneDrive Business account?

With this call, it works with a OneDrive account but not with a Business OneDrive account:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "client_id=".**CLIENT_ID**."&refresh_token=".**USER_TOKEN**."&grant_type=refresh_token&redirect_uri=https://example.com/oauth.php&client_secret=**CLIENT_SECRET**
    ));
```

With Business account, we have:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(13) "invalid_grant"
  ["error_description"]=>
  string(87) "The provided value for the input parameter 'refresh_token' or 'assertion' is not valid."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have always the problem. No idea? It's crazy... we don't find anything with this problem.